# SSM SendCommand taking significantly longer to execute

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-ssm

**Background**

I have an EC2 instance running on AWS that contains a python script. The script is very compute intensive, but is running on a GPU so the time to complete isn't long (about 2 minutes).

I am attempting to automate the running of this script by writing a separate python script to turn on the EC2 instance and run the python script. Using Boto3, I am successfully able to start both of these tasks using `start_instances` and `send_command`. I am also able to verify that the instance is on in the AWS console and that the command is running in AWS Systems Manager.

**Problem**

The issue is that when run this way, the command never completes.

**What I've Tried**

I set the Execution Timeout to 5 hours, but it still did not complete. I also attempted to run shorter scripts that are not as compute intensive (ie: `print('Hello World')`), these processes completed normally.

Any ideas why this might be the issue?

**SAMPLE CODE**

```py
script = """
    export HOME="/home/ec2-user"
    export PATH="<path when running in ec2 terminal>"
    cd /home/ec2-user/directory/src
    python script.py 
    """

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
ssm = boto3.client('ssm')

conn = ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=[INSTANCE_ID])

response = ssm.send_command(
        DocumentName ='AWS-RunShellScript',
        Parameters = {'commands': [script],
                      'executionTimeout': ['18000']},
        InstanceIds = [INSTANCE_ID] 
    )
```

Comment: How are you determining that the script never completes?

Comment: The command is marked as InProgress in AWS Systems Manager until it times out (after 5 hours). Also the output from running the program doesn't materialize

Comment: Is it possible your script is prompting for user input?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case other people have issues. The answer for me was pretty straight forward.

**Short Answer:**
Run your python script as `ec2-user` rather than `root`

```py
runuser -l ec2-user -c 'python /path/to/your/script.py'
```

**Explanation:**

For me, the challenge was that, while I could find the GPU using linux (via `nvidia-smi` for example), for some reason my python script couldn't do the same. The way I discovered this was by running the following:

```py
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

This script lists all of the available devices recognized from your python script. When I ran this via ssh, the GPU was listed, when running via SSM `send-command` there was no indication that the GPU existed.

Once, I solved this, I was able to figure out that it was because the `root` user (that which SSM logs me in as) didn't have access to the GPU. Switching to the `ec2-user` corrected the issue.